# Web scraping Address for a postcode list in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

is it possible to scrape the address from the address locator website based on postcoede.
please please help me if it is possible using scrapy or any other python library.

i have a list of Postcode in .csv, i am trying to extract address inforfation for those postcode
and saved in .csv or .txt

suppose a list contain postcode

```
POSTCODE
HU9 5PX  
OX5 1HX
```

I am trying to get output in .csv

```
HU9 5PX  Aarhus Karlshamn,King George Dock,HULL
OX5 1HX  Abric Europe Ltd,Langford Locks,KIDLINGTON
```

I tried to do something like this.

```
import logging
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from googlesearch import search
logging.getLogger('scrapy').propagate = False

def get_urls(tag, n, language):
    urls = [url for url in search(tag, stop=n, lang=language)][:n]
    return urls

address_list = re.findall(a-z)


class MailSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = 'address'
    
    def parse(self, response):
        
        links = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()).extract_links(response)
        links = [str(link.url) for link in links]
        links.append(str(response.url))
        
        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_link) 
            
    def parse_link(self, response):
        
        for word in self.reject:
            if word in str(response.url):
                return
            
        html_text = str(response.text)
        mail_list = re.findall('a-z', html_text)
```

but the above code is not giving proper result.
**Error : NameError: name 'a' is not defined**
kindly help

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. Though you need to show your attempts and come here with more specific problem that you encounter. Also you would need to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Share some data as example and also what you would expect as the final result to look like. Make your problem statement reproducible.

Comment: @CypherX: Hi, i have added data with expected output, can we used this website for getting address. "https://www.royalmail.com/find-a-postcode". please help

Comment: ```address_list = re.findall(a-z)``` this is where you get the NameError, this needs to be a string so ```...("a-z")```

Comment: @JoshuaNixon: Thanks.... but still getting error like findall() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)... please help

Comment: @RohiniMathur: please check the code for wrong usage of re.findall for address_list but correct use of re.findall for mail_list. If you compare these two, you would realize why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. There are other options for you though. You could use geopy, mapquest has and API, or ideal-postcodes. Here's some of the results that it can get back (note: you'll need your own api key for mapquest)

```
POSTCODE_list = ['HU9 5PX', 'OX5 1HX']
```

**Code: geopy**

```
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geopy.geocoders.options.default_user_agent = "locations-application"
geolocator=Nominatim(timeout=10) 

for postal_code in POSTCODE_list:
    location = geolocator.geocode('%s' %(postal_code))
    print (location)
```

**Output:**

```
Kingston upon Hull, HU9 5PX, UK
Kidlington, OX5 1HX, UK
```

**Code: mapquest api**

```
import requests

for postal_code in POSTCODE_list:    
    url = 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=<ENTER YOU API KEY HERE>&location=%s' %postal_code
    r = requests.get(url)
    results = r.json()['results']

    print (results[0]['locations'])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'street': '', 'adminArea6': '', 'adminArea6Type': 'Neighborhood', 'adminArea5': 'Kingston upon Hull', 'adminArea5Type': 'City', 'adminArea4': 'Kingston upon Hull, City of', 'adminArea4Type': 'County', 'adminArea3': '', 'adminArea3Type': 'State', 'adminArea1': 'GB', 'adminArea1Type': 'Country', 'postalCode': 'HU9 5PX', 'geocodeQualityCode': 'Z1XAA', 'geocodeQuality': 'ZIP', 'dragPoint': False, 'sideOfStreet': 'N', 'linkId': '287067758', 'unknownInput': '', 'type': 's', 'latLng': {'lat': 53.746092, 'lng': -0.270408}, 'displayLatLng': {'lat': 53.746092, 'lng': -0.270408}, 'mapUrl': 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v5/map?key=ZGPYZNMeDbhK2NVXjTQ944ejAm2F1kqG&type=map&size=225,160&locations=53.746092,-0.270408|marker-sm-50318A-1&scalebar=true&zoom=15&rand=-982249466'}]
[{'street': '', 'adminArea6': '', 'adminArea6Type': 'Neighborhood', 'adminArea5': 'Kidlington', 'adminArea5Type': 'City', 'adminArea4': 'Oxfordshire', 'adminArea4Type': 'County', 'adminArea3': '', 'adminArea3Type': 'State', 'adminArea1': 'GB', 'adminArea1Type': 'Country', 'postalCode': 'OX5 1HX', 'geocodeQualityCode': 'Z1XAA', 'geocodeQuality': 'ZIP', 'dragPoint': False, 'sideOfStreet': 'N', 'linkId': '287512940', 'unknownInput': '', 'type': 's', 'latLng': {'lat': 51.830272, 'lng': -1.305073}, 'displayLatLng': {'lat': 51.830272, 'lng': -1.305073}, 'mapUrl': 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v5/map?key=ZGPYZNMeDbhK2NVXjTQ944ejAm2F1kqG&type=map&size=225,160&locations=51.830272,-1.305073|marker-sm-50318A-1&scalebar=true&zoom=15&rand=-1049337783'}]
```

**Code: ideal-postcodes**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

postal_code_df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')    


results = pd.DataFrame()    
for postal_code in postal_code_df['postal_code_column_name']:  # <---- USE THE HEADER NAME FOR THAT COLUMN IN YOUR FILE
    postal_code = ''.join(postal_code.split())
    url = 'https://api.ideal-postcodes.co.uk/v1/postcodes/%s?api_key=iddqd' %(postal_code)
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    data = data['result'][0]

    print ('%s %s, %s, %s' %(postal_code, data['organisation_name'], data['line_2'], data['post_town']))
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[postal_code, data['organisation_name'], data['line_2'], data['post_town']]],
                            columns=['postal_code','organisation','street','town'])

    results = results.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)

results.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
HU95PX Aarhus Karlshamn, King George Dock, HULL
OX51HX Essentra Components Ltd, Langford Locks, KIDLINGTON
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.... last question is it possible to add file path contain code instead of list. as i have 300 postcode

Comment: Hi. i need your help here, when i tried running the code on .csv file saved in the path given as "D:/sourcefile/postalcode.csv", its throwing error as KeyError: 'postal_code_column_name'. do error occur if file contain invalid postal code. Many Many Thanks

Comment: Ya. You need to change that string to what ever the header is on that column. I don't have your file, so I don't know what you called it.

Comment: requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ideal-postcodes.co.uk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/postcodes/CN-511450?api_key=iddqd (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))......trying to figure out cause for this.

Comment: Ahhhh. Ok. Yup that might cause an error. I’ll have to take a look tomorrow as I just left work. But we can fix that (or atleast work around it). Is it possible to send me or post your list of postal codes? So I can see what other formats are in there? I was assuming they were all in a “AAA AAA” format.

Comment: please share your email id, i will share the postcode list. Thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199924/discussion-between-rohini-mathur-and-chitown88).

Comment: can we chat again seeking your suggestion